# XmlDefinition .net core 3 Preview 2

Tags: wpf, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I have migrated a WPF project and library to .net Core 3.0 Preview 2.

In the library, I have the following in AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.test.com/2008/xaml/presentation", "Test.Core.Applications")]
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://schemas.test.com/2008/xaml/presentation", "test")]
```

In my WPF app, I can only call my control with full assembly name, not by XmlnsDefinition.

How to fix that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally fix it by remove project reference, add it again and restart visual studio.